# How to reject tls unauthorized in java?

Tags: java, node.js, typescript, ssl, exchangewebservices

I am trying to convert working code in typescript that send email using ews, to java.
When i run the java code its throws unauthorized error, while the typescript code works fine.
the error:

```
Caused by: microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.http.HttpErrorException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized
```

I assume it because the ts code include this line:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';
```

So the question is how to do this line in java?
Also, do you think there is any other thing i need to add, in order to make the java code work?

Comment: How are you supplying the credentials? Are you connecting to an on-premise exchange server or to Azure? Can you share the code you're using?

Comment: WebCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("username", "pwd");

Comment: For code plz refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64522683/how-to-reject-tls-unauthorized-in-java-ews