# Unauthorized (401) Exception, while sending mail using EWS in java

Tags: java, node.js, typescript, exchangewebservices, tls1.2

I tried to run typescript code that send email using EWS, it works fine.
But when, I run the java code its throws unauthorized error,

```
Caused by: microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.http.HttpErrorException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized
```

I assume it because the Ts code include this line:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';
```

So the question is how to do this line in java?
Also, do you think there is any other thing I need to add, in order to make the java code work?

Here is the java code...

```
@Configuration
public class MailConfig {

    @Bean(name = "mailExchangeService")
    public ExchangeService buildExchangeService() throws URISyntaxException {
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);

        service.setCredentials(new WebCredentials("email", "password", "domain"));
        service.setUrl(new URI("https://mail.address.something:4567/ews/exchange.asmx"));
        service.setWebProxy(new WebProxy("proxy", 1234));
        
        return service;
    }
}
```

```
@service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MailService {

    @Resource(name = "mailExchangeService")
    private final ExchangeService service;

    public EmailMessage sendMail(String subscription, String subject, String body, File csvFiles) {
        EmailMessage message = null;

        try{
            message = new EmailMessage(this.service);

            message.setItemClass("IPM.Note");
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setBody(new MessageBody(bodyType.HTML, body));
            message.getAttachments().addFileAttachment(csvFiles.getAbsolutePath());
            message.getToRecipients().add(subscription);
            message.send();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error while sending mail", e);
        }
        return  message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any one, who have the solution..